# Question on proof of Poincaré-Hopf index theorem for meromorphic differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves

In Griffiths' Introduction to Algebraic Curves. In the proof of the following statement,

> > Let $\omega$ be a meromorphic 1-form on a compact Riemann surface $C$, then $\sum_{p\in C} \operatorname{mult} _p(\omega) =-\chi(C) $.

The author asserted that we can find a suitable coordinate to let $\omega$ have the expression $z^v dz$ where $v$ is the multiplicity of zero or pole of $w$. But I can only do it for meromorphic functions instead of meromorphic differentials. How can I work this out?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can only do it for meromorphic functions"? What have you written down exactly?

Comment: @TabesBridges That means I can only find a coordinate for a Meromorphic function to be with the expression $z^n$

Comment: Right, but 1) how do you justify this, and 2) what makes you think that this works for functions but not forms?

Comment: @TabesBridges Let $f$ be a holomorphic function with multiplicity $v$ at $p$. We may assume $p=0$ and $f(p) = 0$, then $g(z)=(f(z))^{\frac{1}{v}}$ is locally biholomorphic. Therefore we can choose the coordinate defined by $g^{-1}(z)$, so that the expression of $f$ becomes $z^v$.